# what is temp location of filebeat, when it can't send logs?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am reading logs from the console that my docker driver prints .Through file beat I push them to the logstash and then elastic.

but the last 2 days due to some logstash error i'm not able to push the data to elastic so in these duration how filebeat stored all the data that it got in a bulk.

Does it have any temp location to write logs untill logstash starts working again that's my question ?

BEACUSE MY boot disk got raised to 82% in that two days and after correcting the logstash configuration and deleting the old pod of file beat now it got an reduced to 32% so i'm confused and unable to understand the reason behind it.

Please help me understand it.

Comment: Why not use TCP in order to get filebeat log? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html

Comment: @LeBigCat i have modified my question for better understanding! any inputs will be appreciated